# How to import an operator (%*% from Matrix) in a package in R?

Tags: r, matrix

There in an error when referring to the `%*%` operator from the Matrix package when using `Matrix::%*%`. I also get error when attempting to import it to my own package using 
`#' @importFrom Matrix %*%.`

```
# This works:
x <- ("test words for fun", "I like words as they are fun", "they have fun with words")
library(quanteda)
dtm <- quanteda::dfm(x, verbose = FALSE)
library(Matrix)
dtm_ok <- t(dtm) %*% dtm

# However, below does not work
dtm_ok <- t(dtm) Matrix::%*% dtm

#Further detaching the Matrix library result in an error
detach("package:Matrix", unload=TRUE)
dtm_ok <- t(dtm) %*% dtm

#neither does it work to import it for the package with 
#' @importFrom Matrix %*%

# However, when only trying to import the %*% from Matrix it says  Error: '%*%' is not an exported object from 'namespace:Matrix'
import::from("Matrix", "%*%")
```

So not sure how I should proceed. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's because it's a base function for matrix multiplication, not exported from the Matrix namespace. Did you mean `%&%`?

Comment: Please note that the above will not work if I change library(Matrix) to detach("package:Matrix", unload=TRUE).

Comment: Please see my update in the question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `dtm_ok <- t(dtm) %*% dtm` works without `library(Matrix)` because as I said `%*%` is not exported from the Matrix namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#' @importFrom` should work if your function is encapsulated in a package documented whose `NAMESPACE` is generated by `roxygen2`. If you want to use `%*%` in a R session without calling `library(Matrix)`, I recommend you to look at the nice `import` package.

For instance,

```r
import::from("magrittr", "%>%")
```

will make the pipe `%>%` available without attaching the whole `magrittr` or `dplyr` package. In your case, if you want to only import `t` from `Matrix`, you should do

```r
import::from("Matrix","t")
```

```r
t
# standardGeneric for "t" defined from package "base"

# function (x) 
# standardGeneric("t")
# <environment: 0x55f0171c7520>
# Methods may be defined for arguments: x
# Use  showMethods("t")  for currently available ones.
```

That's a little bit like doing `from ... import ...` in `python`.

However, be aware that importing like that a method needs to be explicitly documented if you intend to re-run or share the code (since the code breaks when you use the base method)

Comment: please see my updates in the code of the question. It appears %*% cannot be exported from Matrix; but at the same time Matrix is needed otherwise I get an error. So not sure how I should solve this when developing a package?

Comment: %*% is not an exported object

Comment: Given your last answer, I changed the import example. That's because the transpose method is extended in `Matrix` package from base `R`

Answer (score 0):

It works when I use Matrix::t instead:

`dtm_ok <- Matrix::t(dtm) %*% dtm`